# What is the difference between the use of @Import and @ImportResource annotations in Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have a doubt related to the **@import** and the **@importresource** annotations use.

So for example I have a configuration class named **RootConfig.java**, this one:

```
@Configuration
@Import({AppConfig.class,DbConfig.class})
@ImportResource("classpath:/config/security-config.xml")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RootConfig {

}
```

So I know that in this example the:

```
@Import({AppConfig.class,DbConfig.class})
```

are importing 2 others configuration classes (something like including these configurations into the main configuration represented by my **RootConfig.java** configuration class.

Ant I understand that the:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:/config/security-config.xml")
```

are importing an XML file.

So my doubt is: why exist 2 differents annotations that do a very similar task? Why don't use a single annotation to import both configurations classes and resources (such as xml files or property files?)

This is only a semantic differentiation or there are something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*@ImportResource* is meant to be used in java-centric configuration context. The docs say,

> In applications where @Configuration classes are the primary mechanism
>   for configuring the container, it will still likely be necessary to
>   use at least some XML. In these scenarios, simply use @ImportResource
>   and define only as much XML as is needed. Doing so achieves a
>   "Java-centric" approach to configuring the container and keeps XML to
>   a bare minimum.

One important aspect is that when using *@ImportResource* XML configuration you can override the java-centric configuration using the *@Bean* annotation. This means that you can override the configuration (by changing the configuration XML) without impacting the code. This semantic gives you one context where you can consider using *@ImportResource*, and its in my view a very valuable asset 'cause one of the most common critique of the java-centric configuration is that it requires code recompile.

The second context is providing the means to gradually move from the XML centric to a java-centric configuration.

Comment: Tnx, perfect explaination. Now it is clear for me :-)

Answer (score 9):

- #### [**`@Import`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html)

  Indicates one or more `@Configuration` classes to import. For import Java code-based configuration. e.g.

  ```
  @Configuration
  @Import({ DataSourceConfig.class, TransactionConfig.class })
  public class AppConfig { ... }
  ```

  <sup>See more in [*Using the `@Import` annotation*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-using-import).</sup>
- #### [**`@ImportResource`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html)

  Indicates one or more resources containing bean definitions to import. For import XML-based configuration or  other non-`@Configuration` bean definition resources. e.g.

  ```
  @Configuration
  @ImportResource({"classpath:spring-security.xml"})
  public class SecurityConfig { ... }
  ```

  <sup>See more in [*`@Configuration` class-centric use of XML with `@ImportResource`*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-combining-java-centric).</sup>